# Editable JavaFX TextArea appears read-only

Tags: java, textarea, javafx-2, java-7, fxml

On my standalone JavaFX stage there is a `TextArea`, specified in FXML, which *seems* always disabled. But there *is* a little clickable area with edit cursor in the top-left corner, about one letter tall and four letters wide. The rest of the `TextArea`'s surface behaves as if the `TextArea` were disabled.

As soon as either:

a) the text changed (by user input or programmatically)
b) the `TextArea` once had the input focus

The `TextArea` is fully clickable and looks like just any editable control. When I resize the window (`HGrow` and `VGrow` are set to `ALWAYS`), the clickable area grows too. We tested it on two different machines (Windows 7). Same behaviour.

```
<TextArea GridPane.columnIndex="1"
          GridPane.rowIndex="0"
          fx:id="timeTextArea"
          prefHeight="70" />
```

It isn't a general problem with JavaFX, as I cannot reproduce the issue in a little test application. Any ideas would be great. For further investigation there is the full FXML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.collections.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Tooltip?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.paint.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<BorderPane fx:id="mainContainer" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="gui.RulesView">
  <center>
    <VBox fx:id="vb_tabBackSettings">
      <children>
        <GridPane hgap="20.0" vgap="5.0">
          <children>
            <Label prefHeight="20.0" text="%settings.rules.timeLabel.text"
                GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
            <Label prefHeight="20.0" text="%settings.rules.winLabel.text"
                GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Label prefHeight="20.0" text="%settings.rules.numOfRoundsLabel.text"
                GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <Label prefHeight="20.0" text="%settings.rules.algoLabel.text"
                GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
            <Label prefHeight="20.0" text="%settings.rules.colorLabel.text"
                GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />

            <TextArea fx:id="timeTextArea" prefHeight="70.0"
                GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="0" />
            <TextArea fx:id="trophyMoneyTextArea" prefHeight="70.0"
                GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <TextField fx:id="numberOfRoundsTextField"
                GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <ChoiceBox fx:id="algoChoiceBox" prefHeight="20.0" prefWidth="200.0"
                GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
            <ChoiceBox fx:id="colorChoiceBox" prefHeight="20.0" prefWidth="200.0"
                GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
            <CheckBox fx:id="isRatedCheckBox" prefHeight="20.0"
                text="%settings.rules.checkLabel.text"
                GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
          </children>
        </GridPane>
      </children>
    </VBox>
  </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: can you, please, provide part of fxml code where you initialize this TextArea.

Comment: I did. I made a few makes debugging, so the error description was wrong. The `setText` doesn't have anything to do with it.

Comment: do you have any stylesheet files in your application?

Comment: I do, but there's no style for `TextArea` or `timeTextArea`. Are there particular styles that may have side effects?

Comment: There is an easy way to check -- can you try your application without loading CSS?

Comment: @SergeyGrinev thanks a lot. I tried without CSS. It does not change the behaviour, which is again totally different from what I thought before. I'm sorry for updating the problem description again and again...

Comment: The best way to understand the problem (and description) is to see some code at minimal at least. Can you try?

Comment: Thank you for reading and commenting so far. I added the (shortened, but still failing) FXML file I'm using.

Comment: are you using any 3rd party JARs? If so, does one of them contain the problematic stylesheet?